# Google Api Error when uploading with Supply

Tags: android, cordova, fastlane

Trying to upload the Cordova build using [Fastlane Supply](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply) fails with this error:

> Google Api Error: multiApkShadowedActiveApk: Version 10125 of this app
>   can not be downloaded by any devices as they will all receive APKs
>   with higher version codes.

It might've started happening after I updated to `cordova-android 6.0.0`. Can't be sure tho.

One thing I might add is that I don't specify that `10125` style of version anywhere in the project. I only update the `version` attribute inside `widget` tag to `X.X.X` versioning style.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, `cordova-android` changed how it calculates the `versionCode` out of the `version` value inside the `widget` tag.

The solution is to manually specify versionCode:

```
<widget version="1.1.26" android-versionCode="101260" ... >
```